# Pyspark ML error object has no attribute map

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, pyspark, analytics, cloudera

Below is my dataframe and code

```
df=    
a b  c d    
1 3  10 110    
2 5  12 112    
3 6  17 112    
4  8  110 442
```

Below is my code

```
spark =SparkSession.builder.appName('dev_member_validate_spark').config('spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled','true').getOrCreate()
sqlCtx=SQLContext(spark)
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
temp = df.select("a","b").map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[0],[line[1:]]))
```

When I am executing temp= line I get below error

```
Error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-
  1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 964, in __getattr__
  "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

I am using pyspark 2.1 with Cloudera 5.10

I am doing the above scripting with reference to link:

https://databricks.com/product/getting-started-guide/machine-learning

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First please notice:
There are *two* separate ML libraries:
The first (from which you've imported the linear algebra libraries), is *pyspark.ml*.
The second is *pyspark.mllib* from which you have imported `LabelPoint`.

Trying to interop these two packages is a road filled with pain. Try to stick to one, and stay on it.

Second, as for the exception you've got:
`temp = df.select("a","b").map(...)`
`df` is a `DataFrame`, which doesn't have a `map` method.

But please take my first advice - don't mix *mllib* and *ml* modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot Elior. Really I need these comment to come up in my carrier surely I will take your advise. Here I was trying to achieve functionality that was the reason without understanding was importing packages

Comment: Always glad to help. I for one prefer the _pyspark.ml_ library, over _mllib_.
If you are missing functionality, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

That is because Dataframe simply does not have 'map' attribute. Prior to Spark 2.0, it had, but not anymore. Databricks did not update the tutorial. You can *map* by converting to rdd, i.e. *df.rdd*

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. Now got grip on data. I always dealt with dataframes. Was finding very very hard to deal with these denseVector. Now step by step progressing